# How can i use multi match in re2 regex for terraform

Tags: regex, terraform, re2

How can we do a multi match in re2?

below is the url i want to apply regex on

https://c43545332542.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/new_stage

below is my code

```
value = "${replace(aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.invoke_url,"/(?i)https:///","")}"
```

I am able to replace

> https://

with

> ""

i also need to get rid of

> /new_stage

How can i achieve both in single line

Comment: tried the above solution. c43545332542.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/new_stage, Only https:// part was removed . /new_stage remains. I only need "c43545332542.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: hey @Corion i was able to solve this by adding /(?i)https://([^/]+).*/*/ to your solution. this .*/* allowed me to remove the / and string after .com. You can post  your answer . I will verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
value = "${replace(aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.invoke_url,"/(?i)https://([^/]+).*/*/","$1")}"
```

This should help you match and replace the parts that you need.